# How to set drop box values to unique when retrieving from db in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

There are some duplicate rows in db table. When retrieving  from db and setting for the drop box, it should display values uniquely. How should I perform that?

[image]

There I want to avoid duplicating 2 in the drop box

Answer (score 0):

I you have an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` than you could do something like this

```
$unique = $collection->unique(); // where $collection is of course the variable that holds your collection

$unique->values()->all(); // [1,2,3,4]
```